# PHP destoys a variable if its value starts with < symbol

Tags: php, forms

This is the most weird PHP issue I ever had. Several minutes ago I noticed that my script stopped working properly. To keep it short, after debugging I found that if any variable in POST form has < symbol at the start, PHP doesn't process it anymore. This is super-strange because my code worked for years. Now, this issue happens not only on localhost, but also on 2 different servers (just installed the script there to test). So the issue can't be related to PHP config in any way.

This is the actual code I use to get all variables submitted via POST form:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {$form_array=$_POST;} //super variable with all form variables
```

Then I "extract" array values to create actual variables with correct values. But it just stopped working now. I added extra line of code to debug submitted variables:

```
print_r($form_array);
```

If I enter `something` into form and submit it, result is:

```
Array ( [var1] => something [submit_ok] =>)
```

However, if I enter `<something`, the result is:

```
Array ( [submit_ok] => )
```

The variable doesn't even exist! If I enter `something<`, it starts working again. However, If I enter `something<here`, it doesn't work again. Put simply, if any value in form contains < symbol followed by any letter, variable doesn't even exist. What the hell?

P.S. Adding HTML code of the form (this is COMPLETE code):

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="var1">
<input type="submit" name="submit_ok" value="do">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure the browser is not just interpreting the `<` and the start of a HTML tag? Did you look at the source code of the page? (Assuming you're testing it in a browser.)

Comment: I think you should post the html-part as well. Or are you doing POSTs programmatically? then you should post that. I'm pretty sure, that php doesn't blacklist the `<` (edit your question for that)

Comment: Try this: `print_r(array_map('htmlentities', $_POST));`

Comment: charmeleon, your code displays variable properly. However, I can't get how it happened on 3 different computers (using different browsers) at the same time, if the code worked well previously?

Comment: _"However, I can't get how it happened on 3 different computers (using different browsers) at the same time"_ - that's because all those browsers interpret HTML, it's their _job_ ... and `<` has a special meaning in HTML, as we should all know.

Comment: CBroe, if would read the actual post, you would see that it's not browser-related. I know what < means in HTML, thank you.

Comment: Of course it is not browser-related - _you_ said you could not understand how this _"happened on 3 different computers (using different browsers)"_.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you, since your opinion is "really" "very" "important" to me

Answer (score 1):

I, assuming you're testing this in a browser, think it's just the browser interpreting the `<` symbol as the beginning of a HTML tag and then trying to render it, which fails, because it doesn't know what to do with the `<something>` tag.

**If this is what you're seeing in the browser:**

[image]

**But after pressing CTRL+U (in Chrome) you're seeing:**

[image]

Then it's just a rendering "problem" and my calculations were correct.

Consider adding this in your `PHP` files, as it tells the browser not to treat the output as HTML but rather as plain text:

```
<?php

// This must be called before _any_ other output is sent to the client.
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true in this case. If I view the source, I see EXACTLY the same (it would be better to say I do NOT see a variable).

Like I said, the code worked well for years. and I only noticed it doesn't work not because I was viewing output in browser, but because I couldn't login to the script anymore (since password started with < symbol). So this is definitely NOT browser issue.

Comment: I have the uncomfortable suspicion that something might be wrong with *PHP's* form-data parser . . .

Comment: Well, in that case, my calculations were **NOT** correct! :/

Comment: You could investigate what really is sent to the PHP from the form in the first place, using `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`.

Comment: Smuuf, here's the output `string(30) "var1=%3Csomething&submit_ok=do"`

Comment: `%3C` is the escaped `<` character, so at least the browser seems not to be the villain here. How about `var_dump($_POST)` then?

Answer (score -1):

I have no logical explanation, but once I rebooted all the devices (router, server, computer) everything came back to the normal state. I noticed that after computer reboot, Firefox was updated (so maybe that update caused the issue somehow, no idea).

Anyways, everything is working normally again without modifying a single line of code.

Answer (score -2):

The less than gets URL encoded as "%3C" so  printing it won't work since browsers see it as a broken HTML tag, but if you...

```
$var1=urldecode ($_POST['var1']);
```

Before using $var1 in a database query, it should work.  To actually print it, you could do

```
 echo html_entity_decode(urldecode($var1));
```